# Can robocopy show the console and create a log file?

Tags: command-line, powershell, robocopy

I'm working with robocopy for the first time and have got most of it figured out and working well except logging.

I have experimented a bunch and if I run my job like this:

```
robocopy /xc /xn /xo "source" "destination" *.* /COPY:DAT /E
```

I see my job running line by line in the powershell console.

If I run it like this:

```
robocopy /xc /xn /xo "source" "destination" *.* /COPY:DAT /E /L LOG:mylogfile.log
```

I get a "dry run" file showing me what will happen when I run it "for real"

And when I run it like this:

```
robocopy /xc /xn /xo "source" "destination" *.* /COPY:DAT /E /LOG:mylogfile.log
```

The job executes, but I do not see anything on the console except:

```
Log File : mylogfile.log
```

with a blinking cursor until the job is done. Once the job completes, then I can see the results in my log.

My understanding is robocopy does not create a log by default. My question is, is there a way to have both the console showing the line by line progress like my 1st set of commands above AND log the job to a file like my 3rd set of commands all in one run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you need some [tee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29). (Not the drinkable variety although you might enjoy a cup of that too while robocopy does its thing. :)

```
powershell -command "robocopy 'drive:\source dir' 'drive:\target dir' /np | tee 'drive:\log file.log'"
```

(Or just type **powershell** and then at the PS prompt type your robocopy command piped via tee to the log file.)

**Edit:** Ok, now I just feel dumb, because robocopy has an in-built **/tee** parameter that I can't believe I never noticed earlier.

Comment: Worked like a charm!  is the /np flag so the progress indicator doesn't gum up the log?  Thanks for the assist!

Comment: Yes, otherwise I found lines with just progress percentages in them and nothing else. You can omit it of course as you see fit.

Comment: Thank you.  If you can up vote, that will help me get to 15 on this board.

Comment: @BitBug: Done. :)